# How can I specify a default value for a required field with API Platform GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, api-platform.com

I would like a required boolean field on my entity to have a default value of `TRUE`. I have defined my `#api-platform` attribute as follows.

```php
#[ApiResource(
    attributes: ['security' => "is_granted('ROLE_USER')"],
    graphql: [
        'item_query' => ['security' => "is_granted('ROLE_USER') and object.owner == user"],
        'collection_query' => ['security' => "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"],
        'delete' => ['security' => "is_granted('ROLE_DEVELOPER')"],
        'update' => ['security' => "is_granted('ROLE_DEVELOPER')"],
        'create' => [
            'defaults' => ['active' => TRUE],
            'security' => "is_granted('ROLE_DEVELOPER')"
        ]
    ]
)]
```

And the active field itself is annotated with

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":true})
     */
    private $active;
```

This does set a default value in the database schema, however the GraphQL mutation still seems to be requiring that this property be provided in the request.  I recieve the following error when trying to create a new entity w/out specifying the `active` prop.

```
... Field value.active of required type Boolean! was not provided.
```

Comment: Did you ever solve/workaround this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Setting field defaults in the constructor, or initialization works to actually have a default value... However, if a field is 'required' in the database, validation seems to occur that throws this exception, regardless of whether a default exists.  So on my `create` mutations, I always need to specify required (non null) fields.

Answer (score 0):

Should setting a default value not look like this.

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":true})
     */
    private bool $active = true;
```